# Creating empty scala mutable sequence and adding to it

Tags: scala

I am trying to have to create an mutable sequence and then add to that sequence.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Seq

// my case class   
case class Apple(id: Int, color: String)

var sequence : Seq[Apple] = Seq.empty
for(a<-1 to 4) {
  sequence :+ Apple(a, "green")
  println("$$$$")
}

print(sequence)
```

However it's just empty.

**result**

```
$$$$
$$$$
$$$$
ArrayBuffer()defined class Apple
import scala.collection.mutable.Seq
sequence: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Apple] = ArrayBuffer()
```

I tried to use ListBuffer but its just empty

```
var y = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[ Apple]
for(a<-1 to 4) {
  y :+  Apple(a, "green")
  println("$$$$")
}

y.size
```

Am I using the wrong structure to add my `Apple` to? I eventually want to create a DF from my list of `Apple`s

**Update**
When I was using **ListBuffer** I forgot to add the `()` to `var y = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[ Apple]` and it should have rather been

```
var y = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[ Apple]()
```

And like specified in the comments the operator should have been `+=`

Comment: `:+` returns a new value, it does not modify the previous one. Also, no need to mix a mutable data structure with a mutable variable. You can use an immutable sequence an a mutable var like this `y = y :+  Apple("1", "green")` or a mutable data structure on an immutable variable like this `y +=  Apple("1", "green")`  - Or even better avoid mutability at all an use the collection operations, `List.fill(4)(Apple("1", "green"))`

Comment: My Apple is going to represent different colors. It won't always have the same value. Therefore I cannot use `fill`.  I see, so I was using the wrong operator.

Comment: I see what I did wrong with **ListBuffer**    Like you pointed out I should have used `+=` and I forgot to add the`()` after I created my empty collection. Going to edit the question

Comment: You can use `tabulate` or `map` or many other things, having to use mutability just means you haven't taken the time to learn the stdlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutable collections that you can append elements to on the right are of type `Growable`, and appending is done with `addOne`. Not every `Seq` is `Growable` -- an `ArraySeq` for example is is a mutable `Seq` backed by a fixed size array, and while you can change its elements, you can't append to it. You could use for example an `ArrayBuffer` instead

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

case class Apple(id: Int, color: String)

val sequence: ArrayBuffer[Apple] = ArrayBuffer.empty
for(a<-1 to 4) {
  sequence.addOne(Apple(a, "green"))
  println("$$$$")
}

print(sequence)
```

if you want to iteratively build a collection, consider using a `Builder` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better, functional way to do this:

```
List.tabulate(4)(a => Apple(a+1,"green"))
```

`tabulate` creates a `List` of a given size and allows you to initialise elements of the list based on their index.